# How to avoid repeating chunks of code that are almost identical?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to program a board game called Djambi, most of its pieces can move like the queen from chess. I created a list to save all valid destinations of a piece, which can be in 8 different directions, so I used 8 `for` loops, but the code of each loop is almost identical:

This is the loop for possible movements to the right:

```
count = 0
for j in range(y+1,9):
    if P == 3 and count == 2:
        break

    if re.search(r'[■]',board[x][j]):
        pos = str(x)+str(j)
        destinations.append(pos)
    elif re.search(r'\d', board[x][j]):
        if re.search(r'' + chip[0], board[x][j]) or P == 1 or P == 0:
            break
        else:
            pos = str(x)+str(j)
            destinations.append(pos)
            break
    elif re.search(r'[░]',board[x][j]):
        if P == 0:
            pos = str(x)+str(j)
            destinations.append(pos)
            break
        else:
            break
    else:
        if P == 2:
            pos = str(x)+str(j)
            destinations.append(pos)
        else:
            continue

    count += 1
```

The loop for movements to the left can be simplified with the one above, but the problem is for the loops for movements up

```
count = 0
for i in range(x+1,9):
    if P == 3 and count == 2:
        break

    if re.search(r'[■]',board[i][y]):
        pos = str(i)+str(y)
        destinations.append(pos)
    elif re.search(r'[\d]',board[i][y]):
        if re.search(r'' + chip[0], board[i][y]) or P == 1 or P == 0:
            break
        else:
            pos = str(i)+str(y)
            destinations.append(pos)
            break
    elif re.search(r'[░]',board[i][y]):
        if P == 0:
            pos = str(i)+str(y)
            destinations.append(pos)
            break
        else:
            break
    else:
        if P == 2:
            pos = str(i)+str(y)
            destinations.append(pos)
        else:
            continue

    count += 1
```

and down, because the order of variables that change is different, also for diagonal movements:

```
count = 0
for i,j in zip( range(x+1,9) , range(y+1,9) ):
    if P == 3 and count == 2:
        break

    if re.search(r'[■]',board[i][j]):
        pos = str(i)+str(j)
        destinations.append(pos)
    elif re.search(r'[\d]',board[i][j]):
        if re.search(r'' + chip[0], board[i][j]) or P == 1 or P == 0:
            break
        else:
            pos = str(i)+str(j)
            destinations.append(pos)
            break
    elif re.search(r'[░]',board[i][j]):
        if P == 0:
            pos = str(i)+str(j)
            destinations.append(pos)
            break
        else:
            break
    else:
        if P == 2:
            pos = str(i)+str(j)
            destinations.append(pos)
        else:
            continue

    count += 1
```

- `x` and `y` are the fixed coordinates of the original position of
  the chip
- `i` and `j` are the variable coordinates
- `board` is a matrix of 9x9 dimensions

I want to know if there is a way to implement a kind of function of method or whatever Python can provide to simplify the code above in one loop, and call it depending of what is needed.

As an analogy I think of macros from Lisp, which allow to do that.

thanks

Comment: Providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your problem instead of dumping this many lines of code will help you get better answers. By creating the minimal example you overthink your approach and might come up with a solution yourself. This is far too much code.#

Comment: Break it down into smaller chunks. Figure out what parts are different and what parts are similar. Put the similar parts together into reusable functions. The different parts can be passed around as parameters or their own functions.

Comment: beside that : your code lacks certain things- where is `x` coming from, how does `board` look like, your indentation is wrong, etc. Please shorten and fix. Also you seem to need to regex-search far too much, there is probably a far easier way to represent your board by splitting up data and visualisation

Comment: Encapsulate what varies. Encapsulate what stays the same. Use functions and parameterise.

Comment: Since your code already *works* and you're keen to make it better, you might consider posting instead to codereview.SE

Comment: If you know, *concretely*, what you would do with a LISP macro, you could write a narrow, concrete and specific question about how you'd do that same thing with the metaprogramming facilities available in Python. Right now, this calls for someone to analyze your code, decide how best to encapsulate the logic, and do that for you -- if you were saying "I'd like to write a macro that expands to *this* block, and call it like X and Y and Z; how can I do that in Python?", that's something that would be considerably more answerable than this in its current state.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well the problem is that I know very little of Lips but I know about its macros because I made one exercise of a book for beginning in Lisp which used them. I just mentioned the macros because the result is similar, I don't want _specifically_  a macro

Comment: @Ivc thanks for the advice, I will do that

Comment: So, the point I was trying to make was less about LISP, and more about being *specific* in your questions and examples. That said, a good solution to this probably requires some lateral thinking -- for example, could you represent each piece's possible movements as data, rather than code? (If it's code+data -- say, a list of x-offset/y-offset pairs, each with a lambda that can be evaluated to determine whether that pair applies... well, that's a conceivable representation). That kind of decision, though, isn't really in SO's scope; it's a design question, whereas we deal in implementation.